# SQL ERROR: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql

I have this query and I get error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)", whats wrong in my query?

```
SELECT * FROM contact AS b WHERE b.id IN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM contact AS e 
    WHERE e.firstname LIKE ? 
    OR e.lastname LIKE ? 
    OR e.email LIKE ? 
    OR e.phone LIKE ? 
    OR e.company LIKE ? 
    OR e.profession LIKE ? 
    OR e.mobile LIKE ?
)
```

Comment: Have a look here http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-IN.asp and here http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_in.asp for some reference on IN Operator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The IN operator expects a list of values which match whatever you are comparing against: the columnb.id in your case. So replace this

```
WHERE b.id IN (SELECT *
```

with this

```
WHERE b.id IN (SELECT id
```

Answer (score 7):

The second select should be `SELECT id` insetad of `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 3):

Your [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_where.asp) clause uses [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) to determine which values of b.id are relevant for your query. In order to use IN your second query in there must return only one column.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM
```

the problem in the above statement, because you  are selecting more than one column,

change it to

```
SELECT * FROM contact AS b WHERE b.id IN (SELECT e.ID FROM contact AS e WHERE e.firstname 
LIKE ? OR e.lastname LIKE ? OR e.email LIKE ? OR e.phone LIKE ? OR e.company LIKE ? OR 
e.profession LIKE ? OR e.mobile LIKE ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT * FROM contact AS b WHERE b.id IN (SELECT e.Id FROM contact AS e WHERE e.firstname 
LIKE ? OR e.lastname LIKE ? OR e.email LIKE ? OR e.phone LIKE ? OR e.company LIKE ? OR 
e.profession LIKE ? OR e.mobile LIKE ?)
```

Instead of `SELECT * FROM contact`, it should be a column which contains values matching to `b.id`.

So, it should be `SELECT e.Id FROM contact`